# how to trap the value error in python

Tags: python, file, error-handling

If any file is corrupted and cannot be open, the following code raise value error and stop opening of further files.
How can I print out the name of the file which raised value error, and make the program to run further to detect and print out next file which raise value error?

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for f in files:
    im = Image.open(f)
    print im
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Seems legitimate to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can *catch* the exception with a `try:` / `except:` handler:

```
for f in files:
    try:
        im = Image.open(f)
    except IOError as e:
        print '{} failed to load: {}'.format(f, e)
    else:
        print im
```

The Python tutorial has a [chapter devoted to error handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) you might want to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try/except` bloks in here.

since PIL's `Image.open` method uses python standart library function `open` you can handle exceptions as [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function do. In your case it will raise an [`IOError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError)

```
for f in files:
    try:
        _f = Image.open(f)
    except IOError as e:
        print 'Can not open file: %r. Exception is: %r' % (f, e)
    else:
        # Do your operations in here
        print _f
```

Comment: Instead of `"%s" % repr(x)`, you can use `"%r" % x`

Comment: Good point (: Thank you.